# Does "fill me in" have sexual connotation?

Tags: phrase-meaning

If someone asks you to fill them in, meaning to brief or inform them about something, could it in any way be construed as an invitation for sex, as when a girl playfully says so in response to, "I had a wonderful holiday."

Answer (score 6):

Does it?  No.  *Can* it?  Absolutely.  Almost anything can be made into innuendo with the right inflection, and this one is too obvious not to be so used now and then.

> So Mary came by and said she'd *fill me in*, and I said I'd love her to -- but she'd have to first buy me a drink.

Side note:  The phrases "buy me a drink first" or "take me to dinner first" are often used as *standard* responses that suggest a risque interpretation of an otherwise innocent statement.

It's a casual joke that suggests that, while you might be willing to engage in sexual activity, you'd prefer some *romance* first. It's not supposed to be taken seriously.  Of course context is important and you don't want to shock someone by using it inappropriately.

Comment: I might mention that "buy me a drink" or "take me to dinner" first are sort of stock phrases for that innuendo.

Comment: Okay, let's expand the question a little bit: If you are a man, would you still use this phrase to get details from your funny friend who, you think, may poke fun at you? And, more importantly, does the phrase itself give reason to such behavior on your friend's part? What I really want to know is this: For the native speaker's mind, does the phrase, in and of itself,  create the image of a penis filling in a woman's sex organ?

Comment: By itself?  No.  If I give the speaker a suggestive look, then yes.  But this is why I suggest context is important.  In my example I have the (presumably male) speaker interpret Mary's offer in a sexual way, so the image is of Mary *filling* the male -- which is to say, anal sex.  As a man it's perfectly fine to use it with women or other men, as long as they are the sort who won't take offense to sexual innuendo.  As a woman, the sexual dynamic can be different.  Again, as I said, it's not meant to be taken *seriously*, but it's always possible that someone will get the wrong idea.

Comment: @Rose - If someone found this phrase suggestive in and of itself, I'd presume that person was pretty immature. I'd regard it as a "safe" phrase to use.

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes and no.

Euphemism and connotation are tricky. Generally, if you use "fill me in" in a normal context, with normal pronunciation, and normal body language, it won't be taken to have a sexual connotation. It would be understood as follows (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**fill someone in**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fill_someone_in)
>   PHRASAL VERB
>
> **1** Inform someone more fully of a matter:
>   *"they filled me in on all the latest news from Cambridge"*

However, it does depend on context and how you say it. You could, with the right emphasis and body language, give it a sexual connotation. Alternatively, with the right context, it could take on a sexual connotation without any non-typical emphasis or body language.

In Britain in particular, it may also be taken as follows:

> *British*
>   **2** *informal, dated* Hit or punch someone:
>   *"I filled in a chap and took his money"*

It's called dated by the dictionary, but I have heard it used in this way before. It would probably be fairer to call it uncommon but not unrecognisable.

Comment: Anything becomes a sexual euphemism if you say it with the right emphasis or end it with "if you know what I mean": "I went to the store, if you know what I mean", "I picked up some new uh, printer paper, if you catch my drift"

Comment: "If correctly viewed / **everything** is lewd" -- Tom Lehrer

Comment: @mstorkson: Some phrases are... more *susceptible to coercion*... than others, however :-)

Comment: @LMS [Because of the implication?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/because-of-the-implication)

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. It just means to bring someone fully up-to-date with the latest information. Of course, if it is said in a lascivious manner, it could mean anything.

> [**fill someone in**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fill_someone_in) phrasal verb
>
> Inform someone more fully of a matter:
>
> - They filled me in on all the latest news from Cambridge.

Oxford Dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

In no way would it sound like an invitation for sex. It might be used as an excuse to get personal details.

If for example it was your honeymoon, they might well be saying something slightly lewd. "Did you have a good time? Fill me in on all the details."  Most of us would either be amused if we know the person well, or annoyed because the question from an acquaintance would be too personal. (Nudge, nudge, say no more*.) Some holidays are naturally thought of as naughty and fun times -- like honeymoons, or singles cruises.

(*Monty Python sketch.)

Comment: A nod's as good as a wink to a blind bat!